# Getting different outputs when I change from "--" to no -- on flag

Tags: go, command-line-interface

Ok, I have having trouble with flags.  I think I currently am on the right track but my println in my PrintRepeater program will output a true if I type "go run *.go printrepeater 3 --slow", but if I type "go run *.go printrepeater 3 slow" I get flase.

**testCli.go**

```
package main
```

import (
    "github.com/codegangsta/cli"
    "os"
   )

```
func main() {
app := cli.NewApp()
app.Name = "Learn CLI"
app.Usage = "basic things in cli"
/*  app.Flags = []gangstaCli.Flag{
    gangstaCli.StringFlag{
        Name: "s",
        //Value:  "y",
        Usage: "slowing down",
    },
    }*/

  //    app.Flags = []cli.Flag{
  //cli.StringFlag{"slow", "yes", "for when you have too much time", ""},
 // }

 app.Commands = []cli.Command{
    {
        Name:   "countup",
        Usage:  "counting up",
        Action: PrintRepeater,
    },

    {
        Name:   "countdown",
        Usage:  "counting down",
        Action: GoDown,
    },

    {
        Name:  "printrepeater",
        Usage: "prints hello x number of times",
        Flags: []cli.Flag{
            cli.BoolFlag{
                Name:  "slow",
                Usage: "to slow things down by a certian amount",
            },
        },
        Action: PrintRepeater,
    },
}

app.Run(os.Args)
}
```

**PrintRepeater.go**

```
package main

import "github.com/codegangsta/cli"
import "strconv"

func PrintRepeater(c *cli.Context) {
    println(c.Bool("slow"))

    i1 := c.Args()[0]
    i2, err := strconv.Atoi(i1)
    if err != nil {
        println(err)
    }
    for i := i2; i >= 1; i-- {
        println("hello")
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use `go run *.go`, it's going to cause you more confusion.

Comment: I am going to try "go build" now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flags start with a `-`, that's just how they are defined.

When you use `printrepeater 3 slow`, "slow" is now an extra argument, and doesn't affect the state of the `slow` flag.

Comment: I know go run is bad, but so I understand, "go run *.go -slow true printrepeater 5" would pass 5 to printrepeater and true to go.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean "true to go"? You don't have a `-slow` flag defined for your main app, so that's invalid. I would suggest learning how the `flag` package works before delving into a more complicated package like this `cli`.

Comment: I made a type, pass true to slow.  To my understanding I made the flag within the printrepeater command.  And I will be looking into the flag package.

Comment: No for two reasons. You don't have a `-slow` flag defined at that level, so "-slow" isn't valid there, and a `bool` flag doesn't require an argument, so you would have to insert a `=` to force it to evaluate the "true".

Comment: I deleted the flag from app.Commands.  Then I put app.Flags = []cli.Flag {....} in the main.  Now if I don't put -slow it will return FLASE, if I put -slow it gives me TRUE.  Is that correct?  Also thank you from you time and patience.

Comment: @newtogolang: A `cli.BoolFlag` defaults to false, and is true when you use the flag. Go and learn how the `flag` package works, and you will see how this is a supplement to that functionality.